# Is there an easy way to use glom to get an unknown key from a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, glom

Is there an easy way to use glom to get an unknown key from a dictionary?

the ??? represents random data that I am trying to capture from an API

```
    book = {"???":[{ "globalIdenity":208565940},{"globalIdenity":228049454}]}

    spec = 
    output_data = glom(book, spec)
    print(output_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `iterator` for values then use the `next` call to get the value

```
book = {"???":[{ "globalIdenity":208565940},{"globalIdenity":228049454}]}

result = next(iter(book.values()))

print(result)

#output
[{'globalIdenity': 208565940}, {'globalIdenity': 228049454}]
```